# Flutter Web - how to test flutter web application opens in Chrome on desktop?

Tags: flutter, selenium, webdriver, flutter-web

There is a button on a web page that makes an API call to third party application. And in return third-party application gets rendered on a web page.

Now, the third-party application (https://goknow.me/#/) is developed in `flutter` and I know nothing about `flutter`. I'm using `java`, `selenium` and `webdriver` for end to end testing. I'm using same set of tools for the rest of the application and it's working fine.

While inspecting in `chrome`, the DOM look like this:[image: flutter elements]

Flutter application has a form and I want to find an element so that I can send inputs during testing automation. By searching online I found this [appium-flutter-driver](https://github.com/appium-userland/appium-flutter-driver/tree/master/example/java). I've also included the required `jar` in my project. With selenium webdriver I'm not able to find an element in flutter application that renders in Chrome browser on desktop.

Here's the code:

```
import pro.truongsinh.appium_flutter.FlutterFinder;
import pro.truongsinh.appium_flutter.finder.FlutterElement;

protected FlutterFinder find;

WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='know-iframe']"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);

    find = new FlutterFinder(driver);
    FlutterElement elm = find.text("Email");
    elm.click();
    elm.sendKeys("hello world");
```

During testing automation I want to select fields in `form` and send inputs to those fields.

**How to find an element in `flutter` web application that renders in another web application in Chrome browser on desktop?**

Comment: Please add the relevant part of the HTML as code, the image is not convenient to work with, I do not see the Email element at all in the image.

Comment: I know it's very painful. But on the flip side, this is a very good feature for building secure webapps if you don't want applications to be screen scraping or trying to do anything malicious.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter Web is very different from normal web frameworks such as React or Vue. Looking at the [official doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/web-renderers), it renders either into HTML elements (but still not the usual elements you see everyday), or directly draw onto a Canvas.

In addition, since it is a third-party app, it is mostly likely that you are not able to change their code. Thus, your appium-flutter-driver mostly will not work, because it says:

> Under the hood, Appium Flutter Driver use the Dart VM Service Protocol with extension ext.flutter.driver, similar to Flutter Driver, to control the Flutter app-under-test (AUT).

You know, Dart VM service is *only* available when you run the Flutter app by source code in debug mode, or at least when you have control to the source code.

Therefore, my suggestion is: Can you treat the Flutter application as a "picture" instead of a DOM tree, and try to locate the buttons?

Answer (score 0):

you can try using **io.github.sukgu** that helps you to work on the shadow elements. I was able to automate the scenario that you mentioned. Below is the detailed code.

Step 1 add the below dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.sukgu/automation -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.sukgu</groupId>
    <artifactId>automation</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Step 2 use the below import in the test file

```
import io.github.sukgu.*;
```

Step 3 Below is the entire code that worked for me

```
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://goknow.me/#/");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("know-iframe")));
        

        Shadow shadow = new Shadow(driver);
        WebElement emailField = shadow.findElement("input[id='email']");


        emailField.sendKeys("hello world");
```

Answer (score -2):

Flutter team [recommends](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/web#what-scenarios-are-ideal-for-flutter-on-the-web) using  Flutter for "*app-centric experiences*" as "*Progressive Web Apps, Single Page Apps, Existing Flutter mobile apps*", but Flutter web app can also be embedded in a `iframe` tag.

They say:

> At this time, Flutter is not suitable for static websites with text-rich flow-based content. For example, blog articles benefit from the document-centric model that the web is built around, rather than the app-centric services that a UI framework like Flutter can deliver.

You can read more about how a Flutter web app is deployed [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/web).

When a Flutter app is built for the web, the [page is rendered in 2 ways](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/web-renderers):

- **HTML renderer** (on mobile browsers)
- **CanvasKit renderer** (on desktop browsers)

---

I hope now you know a little more about Flutter framework.